# A cartoon movie where a boy travels to a monster world by going under his bed

Tags: story-identification, movie, cartoon

A cartoon movie where a boy looks under his bed after his sister said "*don't look under your bed there are monsters there*". So he does and gets transported to a world filled with monsters.

In this world he's considered the monster but before gets discovered he lands under a monster kids bed, and his older sister tell this monster kid the same thing: "*don't look under the bed there are humans there*". To his surprise he finds the boy and they become friends, but the boy ends up getting chased by others; mainly two monsters with a globe-like thing to capture him.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this and when do you think it might've been made?

Comment: It could be '[Little Monsters](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097758/)', from 1989, but I can't remember or find anything about this inversion.

Comment: https://youtu.be/E2ZlqJ0n7tk?si=73d-f_XpYheWHIrX

Comment: I was little and it was recorded on a vhs along with the orignal my little pony but it was 90s movies early

Comment: It wasn’t little monsters that’s was live action this was the form of cartoon version

Comment: Sounds a bit like Bizarro World Pokemon.